# Quicksort. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, file-io, stack-overflow, quicksort

Good day! I have here a Java program that does the quicksort. It reads a file then sorts the first 10,000 words in it. I followed the pseudocode of Thomas Cormen in his Introduction to Algorithms, Second Ed.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SortingAnalysis {

    public static int partition(String[] A, int p, int r) {
        String x = A[r];
        int i = p-1;
        for (int j=p; j < r-1; j++) {
            int comparison = A[j].compareTo(x);
            if (comparison<=0) {
                i=i+1;
                A[i] = A[j];
            }       
        }
        A[i+1] = A[r];
        return i+1;
    }

    public static void quickSort(String[] a, int p, int r) {
        if (p < r) {
            int q = partition(a, p, r);
            quickSort(a, p, q-1);
            quickSort(a, q+1, r);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NO_OF_WORDS = 10000;
        try {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            String[] words = new String[NO_OF_WORDS];
            int i = 0;
            while(file.hasNext() && i < NO_OF_WORDS) {
                words[i] = file.next();
                i++;
            }
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            quickSort(words, 0, words.length-1);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Sorted Words: ");
            for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                System.out.println(words[j]);
            }
            System.out.print("Running time: " + (end - start) + "ms");

        }
        catch(SecurityException securityException) {
            System.err.println("Error");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            System.err.println("Error");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the code, the console says

  `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at SortingAnalysis.partition and quickSort` 

 
I thought that the error was just because of the large size (ie, 10000) so I decreased it to 100 instead. However, it still doesn't sort the first 100 words from a file, rather, it displays the 100th word 100 times.

Please help me fix the code. I'm new in Java and I need help from you guys. Thank you very much!

**EDIT:** I now edited my code. It doesn't have an error now even when the  `NO_OF_WORDS`  reaches 10000. The problem is it halts the wrong sequence.

Comment: I did not check all, but this `if ((comparison==0)&&(comparison<0))` does not look right.

Comment: For starters, your if statement inside your partition method can never be true (comparison==0)&&(comparison<0). && is AND - did you perhaps want OR instead? (comparison==0)||(comparison<0) or more succinctly (comparison<=0)

Comment: Another problem is `for (int j=p; j > r-1; j++)`. The loop will never be entered.

Comment: Hello Flavio, Robert, and Daniel! I now edited my code. Thanks guys! Silly me. But it still doesn't sort the words right. But regardless of the NO_OF_WORDS, it has no error. :)

Comment: A Stackoverflow error would be caused by a too deep recursion, you got that right (you can somewhat mitigate this by increasing max stack size though). Your partitioning code seems a little bit fishy to me, you might wanna look into that.

Comment: Thanks @Cubic The stackoverflow error is resolved. I'm now reviewing the partition method. When I'm looking at the pseudocode by Cormen,

<code> PARTITION(A, p, r )
x ← A[r ]
i ← p − 1
for j ← p to r − 1
do if A[ j ] ≤ x
then i ← i + 1
exchange A[i ] ↔ A[ j ]
exchange A[i + 1] ↔ A[r ]
return i + 1 </code>

it seems right because I "debugged" the code by hand by myself. However, when I put it into the code, it's not working. Where can I go wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

- the loop in `partition()` should run to `j <= r - 1`, you are jumping out early.
- You are not swapping elements. Try the following code:

  ```
  public static int partition(String[] A, int p, int r) {
     String x = A[r];
     int i = p - 1;
     for (int j = p; j <= r - 1; j++) {
         int comparison = A[j].compareTo(x);
         if (comparison <= 0) {
             i = i + 1;
             swap(A, i, j);
         }
     }
     swap(A, i + 1, r);
     return i + 1;
  }

  public static void swap(String[] a, int i, int j) {
     String temp = a[i];
     a[i] = a[j];
     a[j] = temp;    
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much, Keppil for providing the swap method! It now runs properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Quicksort algo of wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), the partition algo is the following :

```
// left is the index of the leftmost element of the array
// right is the index of the rightmost element of the array (inclusive)
//   number of elements in subarray = right-left+1
function partition(array, 'left', 'right', 'pivotIndex')
  'pivotValue' := array['pivotIndex']
  swap array['pivotIndex'] and array['right']  // Move pivot to end
  'storeIndex' := 'left'
  for 'i' from 'left' to 'right' - 1  // left ≤ i < right
      if array['i'] < 'pivotValue'
          swap array['i'] and array['storeIndex']
          'storeIndex' := 'storeIndex' + 1
  swap array['storeIndex'] and array['right']  // Move pivot to its final place
  return 'storeIndex'
```

In your method you don't use the `pivotIndex` value, you base your `pivotValue` on the `right` index. You need to add this parameter to your method.

Following the wiki algo it should be like this :

```
public static int partition(String[] A, int p, int r, int pivotIdx) {
    String x = A[pivotIdx];
    String tmp = A[pivotIdx];
    A[pivotIdx] = A[r];
    A[r]=tmp;
    int i = p;
    for (int j=p; j < r; j++) {
        int comparison = A[j].compareTo(x);
        if (comparison<=0) {
            tmp=A[i];
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j]=tmp;
            i++;
        }       
    }
    tmp=A[i];
    A[i] = A[r];
    A[r]=tmp;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, alain.janinm! You're of great help!